# ssms crash/closed after open few minute

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The ssms is automatically closed after few second, It dint prompt out any error. It just open then when i login will immediately close the ssms right away? Anyone face this problems ? ANy Solutions? Update to 17.1 also the same.

Comment: Check windows event/application log for more info.

Comment: dont have any log , that what I was headache. No notification, no event log